# Is there a way to combine or organize multiple Asset Libraries?

Tags: asset-browser

I have multiple Asset Libraries that contain many models, materials and hdris. I would like to organize them all into one big library, rather than switching between Asset Libraries.

For example, I have the Polyhaven addon, which contains rock materials and I also have the Realtime Materials addon, which also contains rock materials. Currently, I have to switch between the 2 Asset Libraries to find the rock materials of each and what I'd like is to have a way to see all rock materials at once. Is this possible?